# Delete all whitespace in MySQL column names from a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am migrating a database from `Access` to `MySQL`, using `Xataface` as a frontend. Alas, `Xataface` is unable to modify a record if the column name contains a space and the people who made the `Access` database have tons of spaces in the column name.

The database is, alas, rather large, and thus manually modifying it seems rather problematic. I have looked through the MySQL manual and have only found things on how to remove whitespace from individual rows.

Perhaps modifying the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` table would be the way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a statement where each output is an `ALTER TABLE` statement and run those statements afterwards.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' 
       + Table_Name
       + ' CHANGE COLUMN `' 
       + Column_Name 
       + '` `' 
       + REPLACE(Column_Name, ' ', '')
       + '`'
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA_COLUMNS
WHERE  Column_Name LIKE '% %'
```

**Output**

```
ALTER TABLE tableX CHANGE COLUMN [column with spaces] [columnwithspaces]
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible that I would not manually have to specify the column names, i.e. that it goes through all of the columns in a specified table?

Comment: @user1470300 - You don't have to specify the columns names?! Did you try the statement and looked at the output?